# Where to input an array of JSON objects via POSTMAN in order to send a request(POST) to an API?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, postman

postman window

[image: Postman Window]

The value on pic(num 1) should contain an array of JSON objects. Where should I input them and how . If anyone can help, please write step by step guide, cause I am a fresher in POSTMAN and don't have and particular skills in programming - i'm doing in step by step according to the documentation

Answer (score 2):

In the body section of the request see attached:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open Postman,

1. Change the `HTTP Method` to `Post`
2. Enter Your Url.
3. Under the Url section. Click `Body`
4. Under Body Section. Click `raw`.
5. Write your Json Request Body. which exactly reflect the **Model** in you web api.

[image: Post Man Example]

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

Step 1 : set the proper method type and API Url and content type in header section as shown in pic(GET, POST etc.)
[image: postman]

Step 2 : Go to the body section and enter your JSON string as shown in below image :
[image: body]

Step 3 : Click SEND and you will find the API response at the bottom panel of POSTMAN.